# Failed to install elasticsearch on ambari

Tags: elasticsearch, ambari

i'm trying to install elasticsearch on ambari from mpack that i install from here https://github.com/steven-matison/dfhz_hdp_mpack

i'm using public repository for elasticsearch, and local repository for HDP and ambari, but the error appear when i install the elasticsearch, the error show "Skipping stack-select on ELASTICSEARCH because it does not exist in the stack-select package structure.
"

the error explanation from ambari-server ui:
stderr:   /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-2202.txt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 38, in <module>
    BeforeAnyHook().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 352, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 31, in hook
    setup_users()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 50, in setup_users
    groups = params.user_to_groups_dict[user],
KeyError: u'elasticsearch'
Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-2202.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-2202.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp', 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2', '']
```

stdout:   /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-2202.txt

```
2022-10-06 13:02:54,352 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster Stack=3.1, Command Stack=None, Command Version=None -> 3.1
2022-10-06 13:02:54,359 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
2022-10-06 13:02:54,361 - Group['livy'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,363 - Group['elasticsearch'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,363 - Group['spark'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,363 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,363 - Group['hadoop'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,364 - Group['users'] {}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,364 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,366 - User['yarn-ats'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,367 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,368 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop', 'users'], 'uid': None}
2022-10-06 13:02:54,369 - User['livy'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['livy', 'hadoop'], 'uid': None}
Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-2202.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-2202.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp', 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2', '']
2022-10-06 13:02:54,609 - The repository with version 3.1.4.0-315 for this command has been marked as resolved. It will be used to report the version of the component which was installed
2022-10-06 13:02:54,618 - Skipping stack-select on ELASTICSEARCH because it does not exist in the stack-select package structure.

Command failed after 1 tries
```

installation status for elasticsearch :

```
Admin Name : admin

Cluster Name : ClusterCovid19

Total Hosts : 4 (0 new)

Repositories:

redhat7 (elasticsearch-7.x):
https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum
redhat7 (mosga-ambari):
http://192.168.20.117/repository/centos/7/ambari/2.7.5.0/
redhat7 (mosga-hdp3):
http://192.168.20.117/repository/centos/7/hdp/HDP-3.1.4.0/
Services:

Elasticsearch
Master : ambari-agent-1
Data Node : 1 host
```

does the error appear because i use the public repository on local repository installation ?

Comment: Seems the repo you found hasn't had updates in several years. Personally, I'd recommend using something like Ansible w/ configs in Git to manage non-Hadoop components outside of Ambari.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in ambari user/group management, as such you need to turn that off before and after mpack install.  This is found on bottom of the mpack repo:

> There is a current bug in User Group Management. The work around is
> the following python command before installing ELK Components:
>
> python /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.py -u admin -p
> admin -n [CLUSTER_NAME] -l [CLUSTER_FQDN] -t 8080 -a set -c
> cluster-env -k  ignore_groupsusers_create -v true

Additionally, another community member found another way through this same error.  You can find that post here:

[Ambari User & Group Management for Custom Ambari Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217699/ambari-user-group-management-for-custom-ambari-services/65081701#65081701)